# Embed Jetty to JavaSE project

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, java-server

I downloaded jetty from http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/dist/.

I can start/stop Jetty server. Also I know about tutorials on [eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty).
But I cannot find info how to add jetty to project on Java SE in eclipse.

Simply: **org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server** is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to embed Jetty you will need the to add the Jar file to your Build Path in Eclipse.

Jetty: http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/dist/

The jars are located in the lib folder and you probably need the Jetty-server.jar file.

How to add a Jar to Build Path in Eclipse: [Where to put the external jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325524/where-to-put-the-external-jars)

Comment: Thank you. But I need add all jars located in the lib folder.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have your plugin sorted and it's now a compiler issue in your project. Check your build path for the project to see if you have the jetty jar included there.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this may be of interest](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty)

> The following code from SimplestServer.java instantiates and runs the
>   simplest possible Jetty server:

```
public class SimplestServer
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But my question is how to ADD jetty to eclipse to begin write code.

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/advanced-embedding.html  - I prefer using something like maven so you have a standard approach to handling dependencies and the like, as opposed to using some bespoke manual process that is different from the commandline builds, or how eclipse does it, or how intellij does it, which is different from how netbeans does it, etc, etc