# Calling java with wildcards in classpath fails

Tags: java, classpath

I have some jars in the current directory, all needing to be in the class path, so I want to use the wildcards convention for classpath. The command line is:

```
java.exe -classpath * org.python.util.jython args
```

However I get this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: G:/repo/builds/jars/edu_mines_jtk/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: G:.repo.builds.jars.edu_mines_jtk.jar
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: G:/repo/builds/jars/edu_mines_jtk.jar.  Program will exit.
```

If I manually expand the wildcard, with

```
java.exe -classpath edu_mines_jtk.jar;ij.jar;jython.jar;more-jars org.python.util.jython [args]
```

Then it works as expected.

What's wrong with my wildcards?

JRE 1.6.25 for Win7 64 bit

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using wildcard for classpath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/using-wildcard-for-classpath)

Comment: read [this article](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html) on setting the classpath. Wildcards work, simply mention `<dir_name>/*`. For the current directory, include the '.' character.

Comment: @VineetReynolds: (for duplicate) Nope, mine is more specific.

Comment: @VineetReynolds: Yep, I had read the article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it, under Windows quotes around the wildcarded classpath are required.

But not required if you specify jars explicitly, explaining why the second command works.

Weird.

Comment: Wildcards work fine for me in Windows 7 without quotes: `java -cp bin;lib/selenium-jars/*;lib/selenium-jars/libs/* tests.StressWebAppServer`