# java classpath with wildcards on windows: Requires semi-colon at the end

Tags: java, windows, classpath

I have been trying to use wildcards in classpath as follows but failing:

```
javac -cp .\* LoginUtil.java MySample.java
```

But failing with this error:

```
javac: invalid flag: .\jackson-all-1.9.6.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options
```

Same behavior for ".*"

```
javac -cp ".\*" LoginUtil.java MySample.java
```

However, inserting a semi-colon after the cp solves the problem.

```
javac -cp .\*; LoginUtil.java MySample.java
```

I couldn't find this documented. Does anyone know a reason?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://javahowto.blogspot.in/2006/07/jdk-6-supports-in-classpath-but-be.html) is some explanation as to what happens when you use wildcards and why javac throws invalid flag error.

Comment: Thanks Suresh, but I wanted some documentation from Java which can explain this behavior as a bug or intentional.

Answer (score 0):

Use Quotes around the star, like so: "*"

See also this answer:
[Calling java with wildcards in classpath fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179281/calling-java-with-wildcards-in-classpath-fails)