# Importing jars from Jython

Tags: jython

I must admit that I'm slightly confused by the Jython import logic.

I now that I can manually add the jars one by one to sys.path but I have a whole bunch of them and this is quite painful.

Adding the directory containing the jars obviously doesn't work.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6179281/407651

Answer (score 7):

The following code should do the trick for you and limit the amount of typing that you need to do while making use of the standard jython library.

```
import os,glob,sys

directories=['/path/to/jars/','/different/path/to/more/jars/']

for directory in directories:
    for jar in glob.glob(os.path.join(directory,'*.jar')):
        sys.path.append(jar)
```

**Better answer:**
You can create a .pth file in the jython site-packages and include within it all of the full paths to the jars you want included on the path.  Here is what I did to include poi jars(contents of .pth file):

```
/home/kris/jython2.5.3/poi-3.11/poi-3.11-20141221.jar
/home/kris/jython2.5.3/poi-3.11/poi-ooxml-3.11-20141221.jar
/home/kris/jython2.5.3/poi-3.11/poi-ooxml-schemas-3.11-20141221.jar
/home/kris/jython2.5.3/poi-3.11/ooxml-lib/xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar
```

After doing that I can then import without having to append to path:

```
from org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel import XSSFWorkbook
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/var/javalib/some-name-package.jar") # add the jar to your path
from org.somename.somepackage import SomeClass # it's now possible to import the package
some_object = SomeClass() # You can now use your java class

In your case you probably want to use the path of your package to find the jar:

# yourpackage/__init__.py

import sys, os
if 'java' in sys.platform.lower():
    sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)),
                                 "your-lib.jar"))
    from jython_implementation import library
else:
    from cpython_implementation import library
```

Comment: Thanks but what about adding a whole bunch of jars at once?

Answer (score 1):

Depends quite a bit on how you are running Jython. One very simple way (if applicable) is to put them on the Java *boot classpath* **before** running jython

```
java -cp "lib/*" jython.jar <arguments>
```