# error: package org.apache.commons.net.ntp does not exist

Tags: java, classpath

I downloaded `commons-net-3.0.1-bin.zip` file and extracted it to java `lib` folder. I have set the path to java `bin` folder and `classpath=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\lib\commons-net-3.0.1`.

`commons-net-3.0.1` folder has  `commons-net-3.0.1 jar` , `commons-net-3.0.1-sources.jar`  and  `commons-net-examples-3.0.1.jar` files.

In my program I imported `org.apache.commons.net.ntp.*` package, and it gave the "package doesn't exist" error.

Comment: Did either answer solve your problem? If so, you should click the "checkmark" next to it to accept that answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- check that package org.apache.commons.net.ntp.* presents in jar file
- make sure that the jar file is in the class path of an application [How to set Classpath](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/classpath.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just adding the directory containing the JAR files isn't enough.  Add the specific JAR file to the classpath instead, e.g.

```
classpath=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\lib\commons-net-3.0.1\commons-net-3.0.1.jar
```

Alternatively, use a classpath wildcard to add all JARs in a given directory.  See [How to use a wildcard in the classpath to add multiple jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/using-wildcard-for-classpath)