# Adding multiple jar files into classpath

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath

I am trying to add all the jar files in the directory below but I get

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException error.

I am sure there is TwitterException class inside the .jar file. Is there any error in my classpath syntax ?

```
mahmut@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Java/TwitterDeneme/bin$ java -classpath "~/twitter4j-2.2.6/lib/*.jar:." GetHashtag
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: twitter4j/TwitterException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2442)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2685)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1620)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:488)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:480)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.TwitterException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 6 more
```

I am using ubuntu and jdk 1.7. I tried the same command in windows and it works flawlessly. Is there anything special to do related to Ubuntu OS?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The * syntax for classpaths is rather limited. Try:

```
java -classpath "~/twitter4j-2.2.6/lib/*:." GetHashtag
```

Comment: By the way, on Windows you need to use ; instead of : for the command to work.

Comment: +1 but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/using-wildcard-for-classpath

Comment: Tried both lib/* and lib/*.jar but no luck! Is it related to wildcard character or any other problem? I also tried to include jar files individually but it gives the same error either.

Actually, I compiled the code in windows and just moved class file to ubuntu. Am I missing anything?

Comment: Are you sure that class is in any of your jar files?

Comment: I found the problem. ~ character inside quotes causes problem. I wrote "/home/mahmut/twitter4j-2.2.6/lib/*:." instead of "~/twitter4j-2.2.6/lib/*:." and it worked. Thanks!