# How to handle with CLASSPATH in Maven project?

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I am trying simple Maven app with Log4J ver 2-beta 9. In my pom.xml file I have these two dependencies (as is mentioned in [Log4J Maven webpage](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/maven-artifacts.html)):

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0-beta9</version>
</dependency>
```

Eclipse sees Log4J library:

[image]

But when I package the app and run it this Exception is thrown:

```
java -cp target/notification-1.0.0.jar com.example.Sandbox

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager
    at com.example.Sandbox.<clinit>(Sandbox.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 1 more
```

I searched for this Exception and it seems to be related to CLASSPATH variable.

**How should be CLASSPATH set for Maven project?**

Comment: it could be like more log4j jar available in your class path and its getting confilcted

Comment: Yes, my own another project what is dependency for this application uses Log4J too, can be this a problem? I'm not sure.

Comment: In Maven a jar which is created by `mvn package` does not contains it's dependencies. So you have to add the log4j-* to your classpath. You might check things like maven-assembly-plugin to create a jar-with-dependencies.

Answer (score 9):

Maven is a build tool. It doesn't help you much *running* the final application.

You can use `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="com.example.Sandbox"` to run your app (see the question [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)) but this gets tedious when you have to pass arguments to it.

You can get the classpath that Maven used to compile your application with `mvn dependency:build-classpath`

That will print the classpath to the console. Note that it will be missing `target/notification-1.0.0.jar`

Another useful tool in this area is the [assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html); it will create one very big JAR with all the dependencies rolled into a single file when you specify the descriptor `jar-with-dependencies`.

Comment: I have tried Maven Exec Plugin and the app is running correctly, thanks. It means that my app doesn't find dependencies. I installed maven-dependency-plugin to copy all dependencies to ${project.build.directory}/lib. I think that the last think I need to solve is to set class path to this directory. How it can be solved when I run my application at productive environment? Is it save to copy all target directory and set classpath to "./lib" dir?

Comment: You need to set the classpath to `"lib/*"` in this case; don't forget the quotes, you don't want the shell to expand the asterisk! You must pass it to Java. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/using-wildcard-for-classpath