# How do I run a java application with maven from command line on ubuntu?

Tags: java, maven

I'm trying to run this [java application](https://github.com/danvega/httpclient-tutorial) with maven from command line on ubuntu with OpenJDK 13

```
openjdk version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.2+8)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK (build 13.0.2+8, mixed mode, sharing)
```

The project is created with Intellij Idea.

I guess I've made the build successfully with these commands

```
git clone https://github.com/danvega/httpclient-tutorial.git
cd httpclient-tutorial
mvn package
```

However, I don't know how to run the application from command line.

I tried these commands

```
cd target/classes
java dev.danvega.Application
```

and got this error

```
Error: Unable to initialize main class dev.danvega.Application
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference
```

What am I missing?

Comment: One off-topic advice: is a bad practice include the folders .idea and target in the git repository. You can avoid it creating a .gitignore file. The .idea folder save configuration related with your intellij instance, it can be conflictve with mine. And the target folder contains compiled sources, you create it when compile, don't needed in the repo. ;)

Comment: Your question is unclear, do you want to execute the jar maven created or execute the classes in target folder?

Comment: @code_mechanic Thank you. I'm not sure which one I should run. I'd just like to use the code in that repo to get the output shown At about 16′39″ into the video (https://youtu.be/5MmlRZZxTqk?t=1001)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, you have maven project which has one dependency on `jackson-databind` which in turn will have some more dependencies i.e `jackson-core` and `jackson-annotations`.

Classes from these dependencies are not bundled in your application jar, so you cannot just run the `Application` main class from your project directly using `java` command, you need to specify the dependent classes on java classpath so that java can load these dependent classes of your program.

Since, it is a maven project, these dependent `jars` will be pulled into `maven` default directory (`.m2`) into your's home path and as you mentioned, you are using ubuntu that will be `/home/<your username>/`, For example your username which you are logged in with is `singularli` then your home path must be `/home/singularli`, you can also check it with `echo $HOME` command.

So, you would find the maven folder, which stores all the jar(s), into your home `/home/singularli/.m2/repository`, now here you would find jars like `jackson-databind`, `jackson-core` (these will be little inside subdirectories, as it keeps according to the package name, given below command example will give you more idea about it).

At last, once you find these `jars`, you would need to specify the classpath using `-cp` flag and include these jars with your application jar which would look like as given below:

```
java -cp "target/httpclient-tutorial-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:/home/singularli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.11.4/jackson-core-2.11.4.jar:/home/singularli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.11.4/jackson-databind-2.11.4.jar:/home/singularli/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.4/jackson-annotations-2.11.4.jar" dev.danvega.Application
```

It should work the same way as shown in that video, you referred in your question.

**Please notice that you may have different versions i.e com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.11.4, I included 2.11.4 as an example, you may check the version in this project and include that, if different versions are there and you included anyone of them, it may cause some issue as some feature used in this project might not be present in that version**

Comment: Yeah, agree but author has not clarified if he wants to use maven to run the project or using classes or jar, so I assumed, he/she just wants to run using jar file generated from project.

Answer (score 3):

You started Java without specifying where the Maven dependencies can be found, which is called CLASSPATH (and since Java 9 also MODULEPATH if you use the Java Module System), similar how *.dll files can be found in the PATH on windows or LD_LIBRARY_PATH can be used for *.so on Unix-systems

Please see the great answers and questions from others before you:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20045263/6250649
- [Maven Run Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1089285/maven-run-project)
- [Building a fat jar using maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16222748/building-a-fat-jar-using-maven)
- [Is there a Maven plugin that runs a non-fat jar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31993945/is-there-a-maven-plugin-that-runs-a-non-fat-jar)

I personally prefer either:

1. The Maven Exec plugin https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-for-java-programs.html
2. Create a fat jar (e.g. with the Maven Shade plugin) that is also practical for distributing your code and all required dependencies so anyone can easily start with `java -jar yourfat.jar` (or just click and it will start on Windows)

Answer (score 1):

The third-party dependency that contains `com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference` (which you can find the pom.xml `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind` is required at both compile time and runtime. If you run using the `java` command, you need to specify the dependency on the classpath. But since you are using Maven, there is an [`exec-maven-plugin`](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/) that you can use for convenience which will handle the classpath at runtime:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="dev.danvega.Application"
```

You can also compile then run in the same command:

```
mvn package exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="dev.danvega.Application"
```