# Read Js file from Another Jar file Using Java Application

Tags: java, spring

I have two Jar files 
 Suppose A.jar and B.jar

Inside in A.jar I have one Js file i.e. abc.js with structure same as like Dynamic web project structure.

Ex-  wepapp/resources/js/abc.js

I want to read this Js file on another Jar i.e. B.jar.
 and A.jar is not include in B.jar they both are separate Jar using Java code.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20150374/access-resources-from-another-jar-file) described same problem (or [here](https://coderanch.com/t/588460/java/Loading-resource-jar-classpath)).
I guess it should help you.

**EDIT**

From these links:

**Solution 1**

Use a classpath wildcard.

```
jsvc -cp globalclasspath/*:daemons/service.jar (...)
```

**Solution 2**

To read data in JARs not on the classpath, use URLClassLoader. The general algorithm is this:

1. Find the list of JARs in the globalclasspath directory.
2. Create a URLClassLoader from this list of JARs.
3. Look up the resource you want from the URLClassLoader instance.

To find JARs on the classpath, I used ResourceList from the StackOverflow article "[Get a list of resources from classpath directory.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923129/get-a-list-of-resources-from-classpath-directory)"

**Solution 3**

In that case, you need to add both the jars in the class path and execute the below command - where com.schemas.Loader will be your Loader class.

```
java -cp a.jar;b.jar com.schemas.Loader
```

And after that you will be able to get resource file as:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/com/schemas/your-file.js");
```