# How to resolve “package org.openqa.selenium.winium does not exist” error?

Tags: java, selenium, automation, winium

I am using *Winium tool* for automation. I have included below jar files into the classpath of my project,

> 1. selenium-server-standalone-3.14.0.jar
> 2. testng-7.0.0-beta1.jar
> 3. winium-elements-desktop-0.1.0-1.jar
> 4. winium-elements-desktop-0.2.0-1.jar

***Java installed version*** : 1.8

When I try to compile the program, I am getting below errors.

```
D:\Incidents\Winium_213716\TestProjects\winium-desktop-sample-project-master\winium-desktop-sample-project-master\src\main\java>javac sampleTest.java
sampleTest.java:44: error: package org.openqa.selenium.winium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.DesktopOptions;
                             ^
sampleTest.java:45: error: package org.openqa.selenium.winium does not exist
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver;
                             ^
sampleTest.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
DesktopOptions options= new DesktopOptions();
^
symbol:   class DesktopOptions
location: class sampleTest
sampleTest.java:52: error: cannot find symbol
DesktopOptions options= new DesktopOptions();
                          ^
symbol:   class DesktopOptions
location: class sampleTest
sampleTest.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new 
URL("http://localhost:9999"),options);
  ^
symbol:   class WiniumDriver
location: class sampleTest
sampleTest.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new 
URL("http://localhost:9999"),options);
                       ^
symbol:   class WiniumDriver
location: class sampleTest
6 errors
```

**Below is my java Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.DesktopOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.winium.WiniumDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class sampleTest 
{
 @Test
 public void test() throws IOException{
 DesktopOptions options= new DesktopOptions();
 options.setApplicationPath("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe");
  try{
  WiniumDriver driver=new WiniumDriver(new 
  URL("http://localhost:9999"),options);
  driver.findElementByClassName("Edit").sendKeys("This is 
 sample test");
  driver.close();
 }
 catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [Winium web driver](http://central.maven.org/maven2/com/github/2gis/winium/winium-webdriver/0.1.0-1/winium-webdriver-0.1.0-1.jar) jar for the mentioned imports

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have included Winium web driver. But that has not resolved my errors.

Comment: @ShobikaPalani Do you mean you are still getting the compilation errors?

Comment: I have been including the jar files by setting the classpath via Command Line as like below                                              
     set 
     classpath=%CLASSPATH%; 
    D:\Incidents\Winium_213716\TestProjects\jars\*.jar

Is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure if you can set classpath like that. You can try like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22965975/how-to-set-up-classpath-of-javacompiler-to-multiple-jar-files-using-wildcard) which sets up the classpath using wildcards in `javac`

Answer (score 0):

winium-webdriver-0.1.0-1-sources.jar   This jar file is required. This only contains the package "org.openqa.selenium.winium" which is missing in your case.

Try adding it as maven dependency if this is a maven project or search for the below dependency in maven central and download as zip. extract and add to build path of your project=> Java build path -> libraries.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.2gis.winium</groupId>
    <artifactId>winium-webdriver</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0-1</version>
</dependency>
```