# AspectJ with JUnit tests by inpathing the main project

Tags: java, junit, aspectj

I have downloaded a large project (Whiley) and am wanting to Trace every method that is executed during the projects JUnit Tests.

There are 6 modules and they rely on each other mostly.

I am currently trying to get a single module working using Eclipse AspectJ plugin.

My aspectJ Inpath settings

[image: Inpath Settings]

AspectJ weaves the code and produces the compiled version of wyc in the /bin folder.

However, when I try and run the JUnit test's .class file through the CLI.

With the following statement:

```
java -cp "C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\junit-4.11.jar";"C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\*.jar";"C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore "C:\Users\name\git\Test\bin\wyc\testing\AllValidTests.class"
```

I get the following:

[image: Error]

My aspect file

```
    pointcut traceMethods() : (execution(* *(..))&& !cflow(within(Trace)));

before(): traceMethods(){
    Signature sig = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSignature();
    String line =""+ thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getLine();
    String sourceName = thisJoinPointStaticPart.getSourceLocation().getWithinType().getCanonicalName();
    service.addMethodCall(sourceName);
    Logger.getLogger("Tracing").log(
            Level.INFO,
            "Call from "
                +  sourceName
                +" line " +
                line
                +" to " +sig.getDeclaringTypeName() + "." + sig.getName()
    );
}
```

Comment: first, it says that it can''t find the file. Have you verify that claim? Is there any file AllValidTests.class in that place?

Comment: second, are you sure about the argument? It sounds a little odd that JUnitCore use a path to the compiled file as its argument...

Answer (score 2):

Four things to note:

- User *Hoàng Long* is right, you need to specify a fully qualified class name instead of a path to the JUnit runner.
- This also means that you need to add the path to your test classes to the classpath.
- In a classpath you cannot use `*.jar`, you just use `*` as a wildcard, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1237107/1082681).
- Furthermore, if you really want to use precompiled AspectJ aspects, you also need to add the AspectJ runtime *aspectjrt.jar* to your classpath.

Here is an example of how to run JUnit in your case. I added line breaks so as to make it more readable, everything really needs to be on one line:

```
java
    -cp
        "C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\junit-4.11.jar";
        "C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\*";
        "C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\hamcrest-all-1.3.jar";
        "C:\Users\name\git\WhileyCompiler\lib\aspectjrt.jar";
        "C:\Users\name\git\Test\bin"
    org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
        wyc.testing.AllValidTests
```

**Update:**

Actually I was busy this week, but I just gave it a quick try here with LTW on the binary JARs, but the `*.whiley` test files unpacked. It works nicely, I see the log output on the console. I had to change your pointcut though because it lead to bloated output in the LTW scenario when all the loaded framework classes (e.g. from JUnit) were also woven. I also simplified your aspect a bit in order to provide formatted output on `System.out` directly instead of all the logging overhead with timestamps because I found that more readable.

**Modified aspect:**

```java
package de.scrum_master.aspect;

public aspect TraceAspect {
    pointcut traceMethods() :
        execution(* *(..)) && (within(whiley..*) || within(wy*..*));

    before() : traceMethods() {
        System.out.printf(
            "%40s | %s%n",
            thisJoinPoint.getSourceLocation(),
            thisJoinPoint.getSignature() 
        );
    }
}
```

**Console output:**

```
JUnit version 4.11
.                 AllValidTests.java:2729 | void wyc.testing.AllValidTests.TypeEquals_Valid_1()
                   AllValidTests.java:97 | void wyc.testing.AllValidTests.runTest(String)
                       TestUtils.java:28 | Pair wyc.testing.TestUtils.compile(String[])
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                       Pipeline.java:292 | void wycc.lang.Pipeline.register(Class)
                        Content.java:135 | Content.Filter wyfs.lang.Content.filter(String, Content.Type)
                           Trie.java:238 | Trie wyfs.util.Trie.fromString(String)
                           Trie.java:193 | Trie wyfs.util.Trie.append(String)
                           Trie.java:312 | int wyfs.util.Trie.binarySearch(Trie[], int, String)
                        Content.java:135 | Content.Filter wyfs.lang.Content.filter(String, Content.Type)
                           Trie.java:238 | Trie wyfs.util.Trie.fromString(String)
                           Trie.java:193 | Trie wyfs.util.Trie.append(String)
                           Trie.java:312 | int wyfs.util.Trie.binarySearch(Trie[], int, String)
                        Content.java:135 | Content.Filter wyfs.lang.Content.filter(String, Content.Type)
                           Trie.java:238 | Trie wyfs.util.Trie.fromString(String)
                           Trie.java:193 | Trie wyfs.util.Trie.append(String)
                           Trie.java:312 | int wyfs.util.Trie.binarySearch(Trie[], int, String)
                     VirtualRoot.java:50 | VirtualRoot.Folder wyfs.util.VirtualRoot.root()
                     VirtualRoot.java:50 | VirtualRoot.Folder wyfs.util.VirtualRoot.root()
                     VirtualRoot.java:50 | VirtualRoot.Folder wyfs.util.VirtualRoot.root()
                        WycMain.java:179 | int wyc.WycMain.run(String[])
                         OptArg.java:322 | Map wycc.util.OptArg.parseOptions(List, OptArg[])
                         OptArg.java:218 | void wycc.util.OptArg.FILEDIR.process(String, String, Map)
                         OptArg.java:231 | void wycc.util.OptArg.FILELIST.process(String, String, Map)
                        WycMain.java:258 | void wyc.WycMain.configure(Map)
                   WycBuildTask.java:331 | void wyc.util.WycBuildTask.setVerbose(boolean)
                   WycBuildTask.java:335 | void wyc.util.WycBuildTask.setVerification(boolean)
                   WycBuildTask.java:343 | void wyc.util.WycBuildTask.setSmtVerification(boolean)
                   WycBuildTask.java:339 | void wyc.util.WycBuildTask.setVerificationConditions(boolean)
                   WycBuildTask.java:359 | void wyc.util.WycBuildTask.setWhileyDir(File)
                  DirectoryRoot.java:135 | DirectoryRoot.Folder wyfs.util.DirectoryRoot.root()
                  DirectoryRoot.java:135 | DirectoryRoot.Folder wyfs.util.DirectoryRoot.root()
                   WycBuildTask.java:399 | void wyc.util.WycBuildTask.setBootPath(List)
                                     ... | ...
```

Comment: It is now running the tests A-OK thanks. However, the aspect doesn't seem to be being woven into it output.jar file. My project files look as such: http://prntscr.com/6jtunz

Comment: Well, that screenshot is insufficient information in order to find out what is going wrong. A real [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) would be better because I could reproduce your situation. Apart from that, I wonder why you use CTW (compile-time weaving) at all instead of LTW (load-time weaving) in this case because the latter would be minimally invasive with regard to (not) modifying third-party libraries. Why do you compile them by yourself at all and not just take them as given and use the JARs?

Comment: @kriegaex: very detailed & good answer.Personally I think it's hard to follow with the question, because I don't understand AspectJ has anything to do with JUnit?

Comment: AspectJ has nothing to do whatsoever with JUnit, disregarding the fact that the author wants to use them together in order to trace his unit tests. ;-)

Comment: I have updated my answer with some source code and a console log.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies in the argument you provide to JUnit. Let's go to the folder with the compiled class and run the command:

```
java -cp "(classpath here)" org.junit.runner.JUnitCore wyc.testing.AllValidTests
```

If I recall correctly, the argument provided must be the class name, **NOT** the path to the compiled file.

Comment: The test class needs a fully qualified package name, too. See my own answer.