# Java program with referenced libraries: NoClassDefFound

Tags: java, jar, terminal, classpath, command-line-interface

How do I run a program in Java, with several referenced libraries, .jar files, from a command line?
I have put all my .jars in /lib folder, which is in the root folder of my project, and added those .jars to the build path.
So my project now looks something like this:

Project:

```
-->/src/Entry.java, ... (all them .java files)

-->/bin/Entry.class, ... (all them other .class files)

-->/lib/commons-codec-1.10./(all them .jars)*
```

Now when i try to run the program from the cmd:
I locate myself within the /bin folder and execute **java Entry**, but I get **NoClassDefFound** exception

How should I run this?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to tell JVM where to look for classes while running the program. 
the parameter that we use to tell jvm that is known as **classpath**

there are different ways to achieve that

1. **Recomended** Add the classpath location to the run command , alternatively pass the jar locations, assuming you have two jar files a.jar and b.jar under you lib folder, the command should be `java -cp".;lib/a.jar;lib/b.jar" Entry`
2. Either put the jar files into a location that is already under classpath (Since current folder is always under classpath, easiest option would be to put the jar under current folder , but this is not a recomended way to achieve)
3. Modify you classpath variable under environment properties to list the folder containing your jar , which is a trivial way for achieving this.

Comment: 1) Wow, does `-cp` work with commas? I though it should be colon on *nix, semicolon on Windows? 2) Yet another way is to add a manifest with the `Class-Path` and `Main-Class` properties - then `java -jar` will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for highlighting , i mistakenly typed that apologies

Comment: Two suggestions to make the answer even better; reference executable jars, and reference the possibility to use wildcards. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-the-classpath-to-add-multiple-jars

Comment: if i type something like this: java -cp"lib/a.jar;lib/b.jar" Entry, then it can not find the Entry class!

Comment: try java -cp".lib/a.jar;lib/b.jar" Entry - a "." in the class path to include the current folder

Answer (score 1):

Create one batch file (.bat) and keep the jars inside that. whenever you want to run then directly run that batch file. I guess its very simple and efficient.

Example: 
@echo off

SET PATH=%PATH%;E:\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\bin  // JDK path

SET LIB=%cd%\lib

set CP=""
set CP=%CP%;%LIB%\antlr-2.7.6

set CP=%CP%;%LIB%\commons-codec-1.8.jar

set CP=%CP%;%LIB%\opencsv-2.3.jar

javac -classpath %cp% *.java

java -classpath %CP% -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss2m  T2DPreProcessing

pause

I hope it will help you. Thanks.