# Does wildcard pattern supported in loader.path for spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can i use a `/path/test-*.jar` kind of path in spring boot app launch with -Dloader.path args.
I tried to do

```
java -Dserver.port=8090 -Dloader.path=/path/test*.jar, myJar.jar  -jar myJar.jar   org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
```

but it throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File must exist
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile.<init>(RandomAccessDataFile.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.data.RandomAccessDataFile.<init>(RandomAccessDataFile.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:95)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.archive.JarFileArchive.<init>(JarFileArchive.java:57)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getArchive(PropertiesLauncher.java:492)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getClassPathArchives(PropertiesLauncher.java:469)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.getClassPathArchives(PropertiesLauncher.java:444)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:60)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:609)
```

Or is it that it either has to be absolute path to a directory or a jar??

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar-property-launcher-features)

> can contain directories (scanned recursively for jar and zip files), archive paths, or wildcard patterns (for the default JVM behavior).

You'll have to put your `test*-.jar` in a directory and add the reference to that directory.

Comment: its already in a directory. if i give the path to directory , it works. but if i use wildcards, it does not. Why i am using wildcards: coz i dont want all the jars in that directory to be loaded

Comment: but the doc says, it can contain wildcard patterns

Comment: the _(for the default JVM behaviour)_ part is important. See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-the-classpath-to-add-multiple-jars) for what "default JVM behaviour" means.

Comment: If you are using bash you can use its pattern matching to resolve the wildcards