# Java NoClasDefFoundError

Tags: java, exception, jar, noclassdeffounderror

My Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: us/aaronweiss/pkgnx/LazyNXFile
    at provider.nx.NXDataProvider.<init>(NXDataProvider.java:42)
    at provider.nx.NXDataProvider.openFile(NXDataProvider.java:73)
    at provider.nx.NXDataProvider.openFile(NXDataProvider.java:53)
    at provider.MapleDataProviderFactory.getDataProvider(MapleDataProviderFactory.java:43)
    at server.life.MapleLifeFactory.<clinit>(MapleLifeFactory.java:50)
    at server.Start.run(Start.java:105)
    at server.Start.main(Start.java:245) 
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: us.aaronweiss.pkgnx.LazyNXFile
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 7 more
```

Clearly I have that class in my jar:

[image]

My classpath includes every jar in my lib folder using * wildcard.

Comment: *"My classpath executes every jar in my lib folder using * wildcard"* - Really, wasn't sure you could do that

Comment: @MadProgrammer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-the-classpath-to-add-multiple-jars  (assumes "executes" means "includes" here)  But please do show the full command line. Maybe the setting is incorrect somehow.

Comment: @Thilo I was under the impression that you could not include Jar files using any kind of wildcard within the classpath, you had to explicitly specify each one

Comment: @MadProgrammer. That used to be the case. JDK6 improved on that a (little) bit. Still tricky to get it right, though.

Comment: @Thilo I execute my project using a batch file running these parameters             set CLASSPATH=.;dist\*
java -client -Dnxpath=nx server.Start

Comment: @MadProgrammer My dist folder: http://puu.sh/kdTGO/ce3ded0cf4.png Also if you guys think the set classpath is the issue, i am pretty sure it isn't because my project does run fine with the wildcard if I revert to a revision before attempting to use pkgnx

Comment: Does your jar file have a manifest with a class-path entry? It's possible it's overriding anything you pass by the commandline