# How to specify multiple jars inside a directory in boot-class-path attribute of a manifest file

Tags: java, jar

I am using java 1.6 version. Os : Windows 7.

1. I have a jar file and in its manifest file, I have Boot-Class-Path attribute and I have been using so many 3rd party libraries(jar files) as value. So Boot-Class-Path is completely messed up as I have to include the path for every single jar file that I use. But after reading

   http://todayguesswhat.blogspot.in/2011/03/jar-manifestmf-class-path-referencing.html and [enter link description here][1]

   [How to use a wildcard in the classpath to add multiple jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-the-classpath-to-add-multiple-jars)

articles, I came to know we can use directory name end with "/" or "/*". But in my case it is not working. FYI: my line is  . Help me on this.

Comment: How does your manifest file look like and how is the folder structure where your jar files are located?

Comment: I have all the jars inside D:\Workspace\JavaAssist\src\SignedJars\allJars folder. My manifest file is  <attribute name="Boot-Class-Path" value="D:/Workspace/JavaAssist/src/SignedJars/allJars/*" />