# org.apache.jena.rdf.model not exist

Tags: java, jena

My java version is 1.8.0.My jena version is apache-jena-3.1.1.
When I run the official tutorials code, which is available at https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src-examples/jena/examples/rdf/Tutorial04.java , the cmd report some errors which include:

> Error: Package org.apache.jena.rdf.model not exist
>   Error: Package org.apache.jena.vocabulary not exist
>   ...

What should I do?

I created a system variable: `JENA_HOME` and its value is `D:\apache-jena-3.1.1`.

```
D:\apache-jena-3.1.1\bat
```

has been added to the system variable Path.

I also added `D:\apache-jena-3.1.1\lib` to the system variable classpath and also tried `D:\apache-jena-3.1.1\lib\*.jar`. It still returns the same errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct form is `D:\apache-jena-3.1.1\lib\*`. This is a feature of Java and the classpath handling.

See for example:

[How to use a wildcard in the classpath to add multiple jars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237093/how-to-use-a-wildcard-in-the-classpath-to-add-multiple-jars)