# SWT, packaging jar

Tags: java, jar, swt, executable-jar

I made simple jar for my java-application (build with SWT).
In netbeans it starts normal, as it need to be.
But when I'm starting it with **java -jar [jarName]**, I have such error:

```
java -jar jarname.jar 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Composite
    at roxed.Main.main(Main.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
    ... 1 more
```

I have downloaded SWT from http://eclipse.org/swt (linux build), unpacked jar and added this folder to the project.

Could someone to say, why I cannot execute it not from IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

The `swt.jar` needs to be added to the Class-Path entry in the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` file.

You can read more about Java Launcher options on this [link](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/solaris/java.html).

Comment: **java -cp libraries/swt.jar -jar jarname.jar** generates the same error

Comment: you probably need to define the full path to swt.jar like `~/../libraries/swt.jar`

Comment: -1. He asked a way to add libraries to the classpath located INSIDE a jar

Comment: @GabrielLlamas - Since he accepted my answer, I am assuming it helped him. By the way, giving a down vote to an answer after 17 months of acceptance is pretty cool of you to do though.

Comment: If the answer is wrong it doesn't matter if it was asked 999 years ago. Full details in Berni's answer.

Comment: @GabrielLlamas - I didn't realize that -jar ignored -cp. Fixed the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add swt jars in classpath. Specifically, `org.eclipse.swt_x.x.x` and `org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_x.x.x`. Where x is the version number and you will have to look for **linux** version and not the win32 as I have shown.

Answer (score 1):

Found ...
But not exactly.
Ported project to eclipse, added all jar-s.
And just exported as executable-jar.
And it works...

Thanky to all anyway for participation.

Answer (score 1):

That's true **java -cp libraries/swt.jar -jar jarname.jar** generates the same error.

This is becouse *when using -jar, Java does not use -classpath values*.

You have to **add libraries to Class-Path** section in your **manifest inside of a jar** package.

For example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: irisRecognition
Class-Path: ../libs/swt64.jar ../libs/bij.jar
```

You can find more detailed description in answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/250166/noclassdeffounderror-while-trying-to-run-my-jar-with-java-exe-jar-whats-wrong)