# packag junit4 not found or ambiguous

Tags: junit, command, cygwin, junit4, shell-exec

I am follow this [link](https://code.commotionwireless.net/projects/commotion/wiki/Commotion_Android_buildinstalltesting), and I try to install Junit4 on Windows XP by using Cygwin.

by use this command:

```
apt-cyg install bison flex make sed juint4
```

the result of this command is

```
Installing junit4
packag junit4 not found or ambiguous
```

So what is the main cause for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Cygwin's package manager (`apt-cyg`) [doesn't have any JUnit packages built in](http://cygwin.com/packages/). The instructions you're reading are for other platforms, like Ubuntu, which [does have a package named "junit4"](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=junit4).

Luckily, JUnit is [only two JAR files](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Download-and-Install), so you should be able to install it very easily yourself.

Comment: where can I place these two JAR on the PC ?

Comment: I mean in which directory ?

Comment: @Hana90 You'll need to check [your CLASSPATH](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), or just pick a directory and [specify it manually](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250166/noclassdeffounderror-while-trying-to-run-my-jar-with-java-exe-jar-whats-wron). There are a few standard places but they vary enough that I can't give you any sort of "standard answer" any more than I can tell you which drawer in your house you should put your silverware in.