# ClassNotFoundException when running an executable JAR

Tags: java, classnotfoundexception, reddit, discord-jda

I'm using JRAW (A Java Reddit API) and JDA (Java Discord API) with Maven, in order to make a discord bot for a server.
When I run my code in my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) it works as intended although if I try to compress and run the code in an artifact (more precisely, a .jar file), it throws a ClassNotFoundException (kotlin.Pair).

**Log:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: kotlin/Pair
    at net.dean.jraw.oauth.OAuthHelper.scriptOAuthData$lib(OAuthHelper.kt:60)
    at net.dean.jraw.oauth.OAuthHelper.automatic(OAuthHelper.kt:32)
    at net.dean.jraw.oauth.OAuthHelper.automatic$default(OAuthHelper.kt:27)
    at net.dean.jraw.oauth.OAuthHelper.automatic(OAuthHelper.kt)
    at javaCode.Tools.Reddit.<clinit>(Reddit.java:22)
    at javaCode.Listeners.CommandListener.onGuildMessageReceived(CommandListener.java:205)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:345)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:64)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:152)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageCreateHandler.handleInternally(MessageCreateHandler.java:97)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:37)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:843)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:739)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:718)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:881)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:368)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:270)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:990)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:749)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kotlin.Pair
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 23 more
```

**POM.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven- 
4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<groupId>1.0.0</groupId>
<artifactId>TDCBot</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <kotlin.version>1.3.70</kotlin.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.moshi</groupId>
        <artifactId>moshi</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jflac</groupId>
        <artifactId>jflac-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.1_386</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-compiler</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
        <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.70</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
            <artifactId>kotlin-test</artifactId>
            <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                            <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmTarget>1.8</jvmTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>testCompile</id>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Reddit Class Code:**

```
package javaCode.Tools;
import net.dean.jraw.RedditClient;
import net.dean.jraw.http.NetworkAdapter;
import net.dean.jraw.http.OkHttpNetworkAdapter;
import net.dean.jraw.http.UserAgent;
import net.dean.jraw.models.Listing;
import net.dean.jraw.models.Submission;
import net.dean.jraw.models.TimePeriod;
import net.dean.jraw.oauth.Credentials;
import net.dean.jraw.oauth.OAuthHelper;
import net.dean.jraw.pagination.DefaultPaginator;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class Reddit {
    private static final Credentials credentials = Credentials.script("[USERNAME]", "[password]", " 
    [CLIENT_ID]", "[CLIENT_SECRET]");
    private static final UserAgent agent = new UserAgent("bot", "javaCode.Tools.Reddit", "v1.0", 
    "Bot");
    private static final NetworkAdapter adapter = new OkHttpNetworkAdapter(agent);
    private static final RedditClient client = OAuthHelper.automatic(adapter, credentials);
    private static int prev = 0; //Saves the previous post index.

/**
 * Returns an embed with a random meme from r/dankmemes or r/memes.
 */
public static EmbedBuilder getRandomMemeEmbed() {
    EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();
    DefaultPaginator<Submission> paginator = client.subreddits("dankmemes", "memes").posts()
            .timePeriod(TimePeriod.MONTH) //Only memes posted this week.
            .limit(100)
            .build();

    Listing<Submission> page = paginator.next(); //Gets a page filled with reddit posts.
    int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, page.size()); //Generates a randomNumber.

    if (randomNum == prev) {
        randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, page.size());
    }
    prev = randomNum;
    Collections.shuffle(page); //randomises the list.

    builder.setTitle(page.get(randomNum).getTitle());
    if (page.get(randomNum).getThumbnail() != null) { //If the meme has got an image.
        builder.setImage(page.get(randomNum).getThumbnail());

    } else {
        getRandomMemeEmbed(); //Find another one.
    }

    return builder;
    }
}
```

Hope someone can help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: this solution will solve your CNFE https://stackoverflow.com/a/33800968/8035260

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ. Isn't export a feature from Eclipse?

Comment: try this solution if you are using IntelliJ https://stackoverflow.com/a/45303637/8035260

Comment: It finally worked, thank you man.
I wish I could mark your answer as the best one, but this is a comment.